# Can I connect a Wi-Fi router through another Wi-Fi router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

How easy is it to do the below?
Are there specific requirements to such a router (B)?

[image]

1. Clients of B should be able to communicate between each other without going through A (Like it would with a repeater)
2. Clients of B should have access to the Internet through A.

For me it does not need to be a seamless Wi-Fi connection between the 2.  Also, clients of A are not important (This might be different for others).

If it support DD-WRT, will it work?

A side issue for me is for me to have the possibility to give low priority to traffic like torrents.

Router A is from the provider.  Router B I will buy soon.

Comment: There are lots of questions similar to this on Superuser. It is likely possible to do what you ask, but may be limited by your equipment capabilities. If you [edit] your question with specific information about the brand and model of each router A & B, maybe someone can help you.

Comment: B is not bought jet (I want to be sure I can do this first).  A is from the provider, but anyway in my case I think it should not matter, as B should appear as a normal client.

Comment: Just purchase a switch and connect both Wireless A and Wireless B to it. This would make two independent networks. You want Wireless B to get its internet from Wireless A but don't want it to use Wireless A to communicate ( which by the very nature of the second point would be the case ).  My suggestion fullfills the second requirement you have.

Comment: The point of the setup is that the clients of B needs higher speed than they can get by going through A (Especially via LAN Connection), and the connection towards A has to be wireless.

Comment: I've never heard about connecting a router wirelessly is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think, thesecond router must have two antennas to have two sets of transmissions. For example this [router](http://www.dlink.com/cz/cs/business-solutions/wireless/access-points/access-points/dap-2553-wireless-n600-dual-band-poe-access-point) is useful

Comment: I am planning that anyway to have rhigh speed between B clients.  it should "work" anyway though.  For B -> Internet it does not matter so much, as that is a lower bandwidth (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can definitely do that with firmwares like dd-wrt. It will split the bandwidth into two. One half of the bandwidth will go into traffic between router A and router B and the other half will be used by clients that are connected to this router.

If you haven't bought it and you are in a place where you can find a router that comes pre-shipped with dd-wrt I would recommend buying that. It can be sometimes a pain to flash another router with dd-wrt.

Comment: Searching Amazon on DD-WRT and Dual band + USB gives TP-LINK TL-WDR3600

Comment: A constant 50% split is not so good :-(.
(With a Dual band, the Internet is a very small part of the total bandwidth, also it should be "dynamic")

Comment: @Olav I am not completely sure it is 50% split. It might be dynamic. I have not really tested that. We have used it in the configuration you asked for , but people used it mostly to connect to the internet and the bandwidth was plenty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the distance between the two networks are within signal strength of the wireless device. The wireless device, find out what kind of antenna is built in, i.e.. unidirectional, directional, or omnidirectional.  There are some Wireless devices that extend the network, but not all wireless devices have this capability.  Most extended wireless routers are limited in permission restrictions  for users since, it's configured off the main wireless device protocols.  This may be critical in achieving connectivity of the two geographical locations of the two networks.  If permissions are a key factor, look into using Access Points (APs) at both ends and connect to a single router that enters the internet. By configuring AP zones, you can accomplish most permission restrictions within your internal network between the zones prior to entering the router.  The router for the internet is on the back side of the wireless device between the two locations.

DK